# Why won't my phone show up as a drive when I plug in the USB cable?

Tags: 16.04, automount, phone

Why won't my phone show up as a drive when I plug in the USB cable for it? I have a Samsung Moment SPH-M900 phone and I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I clicked on the USB icon on the M900 and told it to mount.

Comment: What USB mode is the phone in? It should be either MTP (Transfer files) or PTP (Transfer pictures).

Comment: This phone does USB Mass Storage.  It's a very old early Android phone.

Comment: its a very old phone i just want my pix

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` and `sudo lsblk -f` with the phone connected (maybe wait 10–30 seconds after the connection to be sure)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what USB Icon you are clicking on? You should be able to go into Nautilus (file manager), see the phone there as a mount point and click on it to see internal storage and SD card (external storage) if installed.

Comment: sorry im new to ubuntu I was looking  got it I needed to go to

Comment: sorry im new to ubuntu I expected it to show up in my launch bar  I needed to click on file,disconect the usb replug in the usb and select the usb icon on the phone and tell the phone to mount thank you I was able to get my pix

Comment: @NerdofCode please only use backticks for code and codelike text (ie that we usually see in a terminal, such as file paths). The model name/number of a phone is not codelike. I do not think these need any emphasis, but if you disagree and feel that they require emphasis, please see [Formatting, backticks and editing](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/7707) and in short *don't use backticks for emphasis*!

Comment: @zanna I dont understand backticks for code and codelike text even after going to your link.@Peter this phone was not locked I believe I had to look in the file manager that is what I was doing wrong  I expected it to show up in my launch bar like when I plug in a thumb drive

Comment: My earlier comment was directed to somebody who edited your post, not to you, sorry for confusion. Glad you solved your problem... you can write the solution in the answer section (this is just the comments) if you like :)